# All capacitors leaking on Emotiva PSU?

Tags: capacitor, audio, temperature, electrolytic-capacitor, error

I've just opened the top of my XPA-2 amplifier and had a huge surprise: it seems like almost ALL of the caps are leaking from the bottom. Not just the main PSU caps, but smaller ones on PSU PCB and also on amp PCBs look suspicious. It seems like smaller caps are glued to the pcb, like a kind of silicone or rubber to the touch, although it is really just a thin layer. I really can't say if that is glue or leaked electrolyte.

Just a few of the mian PSU caps are a bit bulged on top, but no other that I can see without dismounting the whole thing. I really can't see how they are seated, since I have no view of their bottom.

Even jumpers seem "rusted"!!! Funny thing is, the 2 "rusted" jumpers are on each of the 2 amp PCBs and are in perfect symmetry to each other. Thought maybe originally they had some kind of insulation and got damaged during assembly, but it is unlikely.

This unit has never been exposed to any kind of excessive heat. It has been, however, under my receiver for about one yr, but there is over an inch between them, and amp case or top was never hot.

This amp powers a pair of Philharmonic 3's and sound is absolutely perfect. No difference or complain at all, high or low volume.

I bought this unit precisely 3 yrs ago, so it is still under warranty. However, I am far from USA right now, and shipping a package this size would cost a loooooot of money.

I work with electronics and I have never seen all caps bad like this, except during cap plague, which I believe is finished and on equipment exposed to excessive heat. What do you think, have you seen something like this before?

Do you agree they have leaked?? Could some of that be actually glue?

I want to hear your opinion before getting to Emotiva.

[image]

http://s24.postimg.org/9oqvo3olx/IMG_1446.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/hk1f2wy8l/IMG_1447.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/3zan3sifp/IMG_1448.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/fn4oyc7kl/IMG_1449.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/6be1nn5n9/IMG_1450.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/ibzhodd1x/IMG_1452.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/w4ihxqt79/IMG_1453.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/vvkx7tget/IMG_1454.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/51pf02qmt/IMG_1455.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/uzt163w45/IMG_1457.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/d4nlbeb85/IMG_1459.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/ps7y1nfit/IMG_1460.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/5wgjzunv9/IMG_1461.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/4rmhuh1ed/IMG_1462.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/4iox4jolx/IMG_1463.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/x9h5gv51x/IMG_1464.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/bzy4jre51/IMG_1465.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/zfg1p3xw5/IMG_1466.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/b0cf1sod1/IMG_1467.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/u7zjye6ol/IMG_1468.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/6jk234a51/IMG_1469.jpg
http://s24.postimg.org/dvpi8nsd1/IMG_1470.jpg

*Sorry, can't get those images to work!!

Comment: I edited your question and added one image. They work. And I think you should put just 2-3, this is not photo blog ;)

Comment: Yeah... those are *not* quality caps by any stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These big capacitors look like they were overheated (bulges on tops).

Brown thing under big caps is not glue. This is electrolyte.

Corrosion might be caused by electrolyte vapors (if this is corrosion).

Manufacturer on website says:

> Power supply: 1,200VA toroidal transformer with 45,000uF low ESR
>   storage capacitance

but these capacitors look like normal, not low ESR and... what the hell is "Seacon"? I can't even find that capacitor manufacturer in google.

However - 2x500W power amplifier for $750 you can't expect too much.

My suggestion - go to some electronic service, tell them to replace these weird things with proper capacitors (Nichicon or something similar?), and pay for it instead of wasting money on sending that heavy thing to US.

Comment: Well , emotiva usually delivers products up to specs, but honestly, saving on those caps was a bad deal! I took thermal images of them under no work and heavy work, and temps are absolutely fine. I believe this caps batch were no good. I'll get in touch with them, thank you all.